# Check if included file is used by ajax or php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I created a system where the HTML is built by php or ajax. Because the HTML is nearly the same I decided to create an include file for that so the php and the javascript can use the file. The question is if there is a way to look if an included file is currently used by an ajax function or by php?

Here is some example code for better understanding what I mean:

```
$variable = "";

if (this include file is currently used in an ajax function) {
    $user = \'+variable[0]+\';
    $content = \'+variable[1]+\';
}

$variable .= '<div>';
$variable .=     '<a href="'.$user.'">'.$user.'</a>';
$variable .=        '<div><p>'.$content.'</p></div>';
$variable .= '</div>';
```

Hopefully you understand what I mean :D

Comment: Nope, you cant. You have to set a variable while it is in use and unset it at the end. You could have it stored in the DB too. I usually just create a new function for the ajax and from there I get the code. It ensures I dont break everything if I need to add something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more reliable to check whether it is included by php since it's a server-side-controlled check. Suppose that file is name `to_be_included.php`

In the `somefile.php` file you use to include `to_be_included.php`:

```
define("MY_APP");
```

and then in `to_be_included.php`. Do a check:

```
if (!defined("MY_APP")) { 
  // accessed by ajax
} else {
  // accessed by php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More info: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

```
if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $is_ajax = true;
}
```

Depends on what you are using for AJAX, but most modern libraries (E.g. jQuery) send that header. Not all web servers will provide this header either, so it's not 100% reliable.

Comment: Also not completely reliable, but it's about the only thing that is generally available.

Answer (score 0):

In your php,

```
    $ajax = 0;
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
    {
        $ajax = 1;
    } 
    elseif (isset($_POST['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_POST['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') //this is an optional method 
    {
         $ajax = 1;
    }

define('IS_AJAX', $ajax);
```

and in your front end code,

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: URL,
  data: {"HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH":"xmlhttprequest"}
}).done(function( data ) {
});
```

and in your original code,

```
$variable = "";
if (IS_AJAX) {
    $user = \'+variable[0]+\';
    $content = \'+variable[1]+\';
}
```